# How to do or code to change the alert message without to change it every time in the alert message box

Tags: pine-script

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iz2Z.png)

How can I do or code to permanently change the alert message in the message box without having to change it every time of creating alert for my strategy ?
I want the alert message to tell the

- Entry or Exit the order
- Long or short
- Timeframe, Symbol
- Price at the entry& exit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below should assist.

https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000481368-strategy-alerts/

```
if GoLong
    alertsyntax_golong='long slprice=' + tostring(stoploss_long) + ' tradeid=' + tostring(trade_id) + ' tp=' + tostring(TakeProfitLevel)
    alert(message=alertsyntax_golong, freq=alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
if GoShort
    alertsyntax_goshort='short slprice=' + tostring(stoploss_short) + ' tradeid=' + tostring(trade_id) + ' tp=' + tostring(TakeProfitLevel)
    alert(message=alertsyntax_goshort, freq=alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
if TakePartialProfitLong
    alertsyntax_closepartlong='closepart tradeid=' + tostring(trade_id) + ' part=0.5'
    alert(message=alertsyntax_closepartlong, freq=alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
if TakePartialProfitShort
    alertsyntax_closepartshort='closepart tradeid=' + tostring(trade_id) + ' part=0.5'
    alert(message=alertsyntax_closepartshort, freq=alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

https://uk.tradingview.com/script/BTSkg8IP-TradingView-Alerts-to-MT4-MT5-Forex-indices-commodities/